# Why can't I import from autoawq which was already installed?

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, large-language-model

For this code

```
from awq import AutoAWQForCausalLM
from transformers import AutoTokenizer

model_path = 'lmsys/vicuna-7b-v1.5'
quant_path = 'vicuna-7b-v1.5-awq'
quant_config = { "zero_point": True, "q_group_size": 128, "w_bit": 4, "version": "GEMM" }

# Load model
model = AutoAWQForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model_path)
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_path, trust_remote_code=True)
```

The error is:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-10f3d88ac51c> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 from awq import AutoAWQForCausalLM
      2 from transformers import AutoTokenizer
      3 
      4 model_path = 'facebook/opt-6.7b'
      5 quant_path = "/Content/drive/models/opt-6.7b-awq"

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/awq/__init__.py in <module>
      1 __version__ = "0.1.8"
----> 2 from awq.models.auto import AutoAWQForCausalLM

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/awq/models/__init__.py in <module>
----> 1 from .mpt import MptAWQForCausalLM
      2 from .llama import LlamaAWQForCausalLM
      3 from .opt import OptAWQForCausalLM
      4 from .falcon import FalconAWQForCausalLM
      5 from .bloom import BloomAWQForCausalLM

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/awq/models/mpt.py in <module>
     72 from awq.utils.utils import set_module_name
     73 from awq.modules.fused.block import MPTBlock
---> 74 from awq.modules.fused.model import MPTModel
     75 
     76 class MptFuser:

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/awq/modules/fused/model.py in <module>
      3 from typing import List
      4 from awq.utils import fused_utils
----> 5 from transformers.modeling_outputs import BaseModelOutputWithPast, MoeModelOutputWithPast
      6 from awq.modules.fused.block import MPTBlock, FalconDecoderLayer, LlamaLikeBlock, MixtralBlock
      7 

ImportError: cannot import name 'MoeModelOutputWithPast' from 'transformers.modeling_outputs' (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/modeling_outputs.py)
```

Answer (score 3):

You may try to update the transformer version, it works for me:

```
pip install transformers==4.36.0
```